# How to programmatically create 3D array that increments to a defined number, resets to zero, and increments again?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Starting with this initial 2D array:

```
var initialArray = [[2,3],[6,7],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3]];
```

I need to create this 3D array programmatically:

```
var fullArray = [

[[2,3],[6,7],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3]],

[[3,4],[0,1],[5,6],[2,3],[6,7],[3,4]],

[[4,5],[1,2],[6,7],[3,4],[0,1],[4,5]],

[[5,6],[2,3],[0,1],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6]],

[[6,7],[3,4],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3],[6,7]],

[[0,1],[4,5],[2,3],[6,7],[3,4],[0,1]],

[[1,2],[5,6],[3,4],[0,1],[4,5],[1,2]],

[[2,3],[6,7],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3]],

[[3,4],[0,1],[5,6],[2,3],[6,7],[3,4]],

[[4,5],[1,2],[6,7],[3,4],[0,1],[4,5]],

[[5,6],[2,3],[0,1],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6]]

];
```

See the pattern?

On each pair, the [0] position should increment to 6 (from any starting number <= 6) and then reset to 0 and then continue incrementing. Similarly, the [1] position should increment to 7 (from any starting number <= 7) and then reset to 1 and then continue incrementing.

In this example, there are 10 2D arrays contained in the fullArray. However, I need this number to be a variable. Something like this:

```
var numberOf2DArraysInFullArray = 12;
```

Furthermore, the initial array should be flexible so that initialArray values can be rearranged like this (but with the same iteration follow-through rules stated above):

```
var initialArray = [[6,7],[2,3],[5,6],[4,5],[1,2],[6,7]];
```

Any thoughts on how to programmatically create this structure?
Stumped on how to gracefully pull this off.
Feedback greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, I've separated the methods, and I made it so if instead of pairs it's an N size array and you want the `[2]` to increase up to `8` and reset to `2`, if that's not needed you can simplify the of the loop `for(var j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j++)`

```js
var initialArray = [[2,3],[6,7],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3]];
var create3DArray = function(array, size){
  var newArray = [initialArray];
  for(var i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    newArray.push(getNextArrayRow(newArray[i]));
  }
  return newArray;
}
var getNextArrayRow = function(array){
  var nextRow = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    var innerArray = array[i];
    var nextElement = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j++)
    {
      var value = (innerArray[j] + 1) % (7 + j);
      value = value === 0 ? j : value;
      nextElement.push(value);
    }
    nextRow.push(nextElement);
  }
  return nextRow;
}
console.log(create3DArray(initialArray,3));
```

Note, the results from running the snippet are a bit difficult to read...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var initialArray = [[2,3],[6,7],[4,5],[1,2],[5,6],[2,3]];
var numOfArrays = 10;

// get a range array [0, 1, 2, ...]
var range = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numOfArrays; i++) {
 range.push(i);
}

var result = range.reduce(function(prev, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
   return prev;
    }
    prev.push(transformArray(prev[index - 1]));
    return prev;
}, [initialArray])

console.log(result);

function transformArray(arr) {
 return arr.map(transformSubArray)
}

function transformSubArray(arr) {
 return arr.map(function(val) {
   return val == 7 ? 0 : val + 1;
  })
}
```

Here's a pretty simple functional-ish implementation